# How to create a WMI property dynamically?

Tags: class, properties, wmi

I want to create properties dynamically, when the user retrieves the instances of my class.
Implementation in c++, but Put can't create properties on the fly.

Can someone point me to the function(s) I need to use to "fill" a empty class on the fly with properties and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can, or at least not directly, as WMI classes need to be pre-defined. However you could associate with multiple instances of a WMI class which has Name and Value properties.